# How to select zero result mysql?

Tags: mysql, null, zero

I want to return a select query with zero result. When I type this query:

```
Select NULL .... from ....
```

It returns `NULL` value as a result. But I want to return zero result instead of `NULL`. So, how to do that?  I use `coalesce` but if I have value, it doesn't return zero. So, what should select query use to return zero value? I use MYSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add column to existing columns you can use the below instead.

*`Select *,0 as ZeroColumn from ....`*

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you want to do this, but if you do it's quite simple. `SELECT 0` will return zero once. `SELECT 0 FROM MyTable` will return zero once for each record in `MyTable`.